# Outputting PHP into an HTML table

Tags: php, html

I want to put my outputted PHP into a table but it doesn't like it...

The layout I want is like this

ROW - Desctiption URL
ROW2- Meta Description

And it needs to keep this same layout even when I enter more then one URL.

What happens now is that when I input lots of urls it puts all of the same parts into the same cell.. How can I change this?

Sorry its hard to explain...

Here is the code:

```
<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
//make the array 
$TAarray = explode("\n", strip_tags($_POST['TAData'])); 

foreach ($TAarray as $key => &$line) {
        $line = trim($line); 
        // get the meta data for each url
        $tags = get_meta_tags($line);

        echo '<tr>';
        echo (isset($tags['description']))?"<tr><td>Description($line)</td>  </tr>".$tags['description']:"<tr><td>Description($line)</td></tr><tr><td>No Meta    Description</td></tr>.";
        echo '</tr>';
}

?>
```

Comment: maybe the '<table>' tag is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some awkward HTML there.. Try doing it like this:

```
//start the table
echo "<table>";
foreach ($TAarray as $key => &$line) {
        $line = trim($line); 
        // get the meta data for each url
        $tags = get_meta_tags($line);

        //start a new row in the table
        echo '<tr>';
        if(isset($tags['description'])){
            //add two cells to the table.
            echo "<td>Description($line)</td>";
            echo "<td>{$tags['description']}</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>Description($line)</td>"
            echo "<td>No Meta Description</td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//make the array 
$data='http://stackoverflow.com 
 http://ebay.com/';
$TAarray = explode("\n", strip_tags($data)); 
echo "<table>";
foreach ($TAarray as $key => &$line) {
        $line = trim($line); 
        // get the meta data for each url
        $tags = get_meta_tags($line);

        echo '<tr>';
        if(isset($tags['description'])){

        echo "<tr><td>Description($line):".$tags['description']:" </td> "; else{

            "</tr><tr><td>Description($line)</td></tr><tr><td>No Meta    Description</td></tr>.";
        echo '</tr>';
        }
}
echo "</table>";
```